# What are the meaning of the abbreviations DNE, needs,needs-triage and so on?

Tags: security

[https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/main.html](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-security/cve/main.html)
[ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxWWv.png)

What are the meaning of the abbreviations DNE, needs,needs-triage and so on?

Comment: (Partial?) cross-site duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134269/how-to-read-cve-2016-5696-correctly indicates that "DNE" stands for "does not exist" (i.e. a vulnerability is not in a particular version of Ubuntu because that version doesn't have the affected package at all, as I understand it from a cursory reading).